# How do I write a function that takes the average of a list of numbers

Tags: function, for-loop, python-3.x, average

I want to avoid importing different modules as that is mostly what I have found while looking online.  I am stuck with this bit of code and I don't really know how to fix it or improve on it.  Here's what I've got so far.

```
def avg(lst):
    '''lst is a list that contains lists of numbers; the
    function prints, one per line, the average of each list'''
    for i[0:-1] in lst:
        return (sum(i[0:-1]))//len(i)
```

Again, I'm quite new and this for loops jargon is quite confusing to me, so if someone could help me get it so the output of, say, a list of grades would be different lines containing the averages. So if for `lst` I inserted `grades = [[95,92,86,87], [66,54], [89,72,100], [33,0,0]]`, it would have 4 lines that all had the averages of those sublists.  I also am to assume in the function that the sublists could have any amount of grades, but I can assume that the lists have non-zero values.

Edit1: @ jramirez, could you explain what that is doing differently than mine possible?  I don't doubt that it is better or that it will work but I still don't really understand how to recreate this myself... regardless, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
def grade_average(grades):
    for grade in grades:
        avg = 0
        for num in grade:
            avg += num

        avg = avg / len(grade)

        print ("Average for " + str(grade) + " is = " + str(avg))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    grades = [[95,92,86,87],[66,54],[89,72,100],[33,0,0]]    
    grade_average(grades)
```

Result:

`Average for [95, 92, 86, 87] is = 90.0`

`Average for [66, 54] is = 60.0`

`Average for [89, 72, 100] is = 87.0`

`Average for [33, 0, 0] is = 11.0`

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code: the extraneous indexing of `i`; the use of `//` to truncate he averate (use round if you want to round it); and the use of return in the loop, so it would stop after the first average.  Your docstring says 'print' but you return instead.  This is actually a good thing.  Functions should not print the result they calculate, as that make the answer inaccessible to further calculation. Here is how I would write this, as a generator function.

```
def averages(gradelists):
'''Yield average for each gradelist.'''
for glist in gradelists:
    yield sum(glist) /len(glist)

print(list(averages(
        [[95,92,86,87], [66,54], [89,72,100], [33,0,0]])))
```

`[90.0, 60.0, 87.0, 11.0]`

To return a list, change the body of the function to (beginner version)

```
ret = []
for glist in gradelists:
    ret.append(sum(glist) /len(glist))
return ret
```

or (more advanced, using list comprehension)

```
return [sum(glist) /len(glist) for glist in gradelists]
```

However, I really recommend learning about iterators, generators, and generator functions (defined with yield).